# For which integers $a,b,c,d$ does $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

A long time ago one of my professors gave me this question. He didn't know the answer and has since passed away.

> For which $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ does $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$?

It's a cute problem, but I don't have a solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

> What about if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are $a, b,c, d$ positive?

Comment: There is no solution for positive values. Also, you should mention in your question that you are looking for integer solutions (which I only gathered by seeing the tag diophantine-equations.)

Comment: For $\mathbf R$, it defines a cubic surface in $P^3(\mathbf R)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer that may help for a related equation:
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a+c}{b+d}$$

We will keep careful track of which quantities may be zero. To start, we know that $b, d, b+d \neq 0$ because they are in the denominator.

Let's multiply both sides by  $b\cdot d \cdot (b+d)$:

$$\begin{align*}ad(b+d) + bc(b+d) &= (a + c)bd\\
abd + ad^2 + b^2c + bcd &= abd + bcd\\
abd + ad^2 + b^2c + bcd - abd - bcd &= 0\\
\fbox{$ad^2 + b^2 c$ = $0$}
\end{align*}$$

Here's an example assignment that satisfies this equation: 
$$\begin{align*}a &= 5\\b&=3\\c&=-20\\d&=6\\\end{align*} $$

---

For fun, here is a nomogram that allows you to find such collections of numbers:
[image: nomogram for "dream" fraction equation]

You can draw any line passing through, say, the B and C axes, and any line passing through the A and D axes. If the two lines meet at the same point on the central vertical axis, then the corresponding points $(a, b, c, d)$ satisfy the equation.

In the picture, the dashed lines show an example. Here, we see that the equation is satisfied when $a = 4$, $b=3$, $c=-1$, and $d=1.5$.

Also, if you specify any four of the following five variables—a value for $a$, a value  for $b$, a value for $c$, a value for $d$, a spot on the central axis— you can "solve" for the remaining point.

Comment: Thanks! This is the question I meant to ask. I asked it correctly [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1861846/354520).

Comment: Now that you posted this as an answer to the other quesiton, I think you should delete this one.